# Mapping the European Debt Crisis

Tags: carto, google-fusion-tables

I'm a journalist based in Paris, and for a project I'm working on, I would like to display how public debt rose dramatically across Europe during the crisis. My plan is to show each country's ratio of debt/GDP between the years 2000 and 2010 inclusive. Any country with a ratio under 50% will be shown in green, anything from 50-60% in lighter green or yellow, etc. I'm just not sure of the most effective way to portray this, using Cartodb. I'm really new to the software and to geographic visuals in general. Thanks for your help!

Comment: Welcome to the site.  Do you have a mockup that you could share, or are you interested primarily in the steps necessary to achieve your objectives?

Comment: do you want to Display the ratios for 2000 and 2010 in the same map? Or create two maps? The latter might be more straight Forward. When you post your first draft for the visualisation we can probably give help to improve the visuals.

Answer (score 1):

I see that you (or someone else?) has included the google-fusion-tables tag. What you're trying to achieve is pretty straightforward with Fusion Tables. You'll need your public debt numbers per country/per time period (of course), but you'll also need KML outlines of each country to use in Fusion Tables. If you don't have the boundaries already, you can download boundaries from www.naturalearthdata.com under the "cultural" tab, and probably some version of the admin boundaries. You'll need to convert the shapefiles to KML, but you can use [this web-based tool](http://www.shpescape.com/ft/) to achieve that goal.

Now use a spreadsheet tool like Excel or OpenOffice to create a spreadsheet with each row representing a country with the various bits of information you want associated with the country. Include a column for the KML, pasting in the KML you created in the step above. Now upload this to Google Fusion Tables. I think the KML column will automagically be recognized as type "Location". If not, click the drop-down arrow at the top of the column, select "Change" and set the "Type" to "Location".

On the map tab, click "Change Map Features" and select the "Buckets" tab. Select the number of buckets you want to use, select the column that has the values that will determine the color, and create a bucket and color for each range you want to show. Then click "Save".

(This should be pretty close - I'm on a terrible internet connection so I can't actually verify certain parts of this answer, but surely someone will edit any errors.)

Answer (score 1):

From what I understand of your question, it appears that the map you're seeking to create will be fairly straightforward. If you've already calculated the ratios in question, simply add them to a table that contains geometries for European countries; the free 'tm_world_borders' table provided by CartoDB under the "Common Data" tab would I suspect work well. If the boundaries from that file are too jagged for your purposes, let me know and I can quickly pull together a more refined boundary file using GIS software, which I could then send to you for uploading into your CartoDB account.

Once you have the table ready, open it up, add a new column (I'll call it debt_GDP) and input the ratios for each country, with 1 equal to 100% debt/GDP, 0.50 = 50%, 1.25 = 125%, etc.. From here, go to the 'Map View' and begin constructing your visualization. Open the 'Wizard' tool (the one just below the 'SQL' tool), and select the 'Choropleth' option. Now select the newly created debt_GDP column, and modify the display as desired such that you have the appropriate breakdown and color scheme.

If you've any questions, or if I misunderstood your query in some way, don't hesitate to post a follow up.